# Server/client UDP, sender uses a random port

Tags: c, sockets, udp, port

I am trying to do a simple client/server chat example using `UDP` sockets.

The idea is to have 2 applications running on 2 different PCs. Each program is both client and server.

The server is bind on `0.0.0.0` port `9999` and the client is using as well the port `9999`.

```
client_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
other_address.sin_family = AF_INET;
other_address.sin_port = htons(9999);
other_address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(192.168.1.42); 
sendto(client_socket, data, size,
    0, other_address, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
```

On Wireshark I can see the origin port is random chosen from 53783 to 57229.

```
Source       Destination  Protocol  Info
192.168.1.6  192.168.1.42  UDP      57229 -> 9999
192.168.1.42 192.168.1.6   UDP      53783 -> 9999
```

What is my mistake?

Comment: Why do you think you made a mistake?

Comment: Because I want to have `9999 -> 9999` same port on both side. I guess this is the normal behavior, but I don't understand the theory behind this.

Comment: If you want `9999 -> 9999` on both sides, you'd have to bind your client as well. But you do not really want it. It shouldn't matter which port is used by your client.

Comment: `netstat -oan` or `netstat -oan | find "9999"` will generally give you the same information. The numbers you see there aren't indicating you did anything wrong, they're just local ports Windows is using to handle the connections. The outgoing/incoming port should still be on 9999, despite what that says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What is my mistake?

If you want your UDP packets to be sent from a port that you choose, you'll need to call bind() on your sending UDP socket to specify the (non-zero) port that you want the socket to be sending from (and listening on).  If you don't, then the OS will choose an available port to send from, as you have seen.

Note that that isn't necessarily a bad thing:  it's often preferable to let the OS choose a port for you, since that way you avoid the possible failure that would occur if the port you specified was unavailable because some other program was already using it.  The receiving (server) program can read in the UDP packets using recvfrom() to find out the IP address and port number they came from, so there's no reason it can't reply to your UDP packets even if your UDP packets aren't coming from a "well-known" port.

Comment: Does it mean that my program cannot bind two different sockets on the same port on same IP (as I have a server socket already bind and a client socket)?

Comment: It is possible for a program to bind two sockets to the same port (by specifying that it wants to do so via a call to setsockopt() with the SO_REUSEADDR flag), but it's not something you generally want or need to do.  If you are trying to run two copies of your program simultaneously on the same computer, you'll want to have them bind to different port numbers, otherwise there will be no way for the OS to know which UDP packets is supposed to be given to which program. If you're running on two different computers then they can use the same port number (since the IP addresses will be different)

Comment: Actually I think you would need `SO_REUSEPORT`, not `SO_REUSEADDR` to bind 2x sockets to UDP port 9999 on the same IP.

Comment: Hmm, you may be right.  When I want to bind multiple sockets to a single UDP port, I use SO_REUSEADDR on every OS, and under MacOS/X (and I think any BSD-based OS) SO_REUSEPORT as well.